# Which url structure is recommended SEO practice, or that does not matter much nowdays?

Tags: seo, url

Which is recommended approach to categorize and form URL structure nowadays?
Should we do it by template type, or skip that part, and go directly for slugs, or split URLs in to deep structure?

Here are several examples, of which I'm trying to find out which one will suit us best:

```
/100-most-popular-foods-in-italy
/lists/100-most-popular-foods-in-italy
/lists/italy/100-popular-foods
/italy/100-most-popular-foods
/italy/foods/popular/100
```

Answer (score 3):

I would skip the "lists" fragment, since it gives no real info to the user. The most important thing is probably that it looks good on the SERP. Play around with it on https://www.highervisibility.com/seo/tools/serp-snippet-optimizer/ and see which breadcrumb that looks best in the preview.

The most informational IMO is mypage.com/italy/100-most-popular-foods, but that is of course depending on you having a great landing page for /italy as well. I can see people clicking directly to "Italy"-breadcrumb, but not necessarily "Lists"

Google has some recommendations here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/url-structure Simple and descriptive is the key.